# Oracle: Possible to return nothing from PL/SQL function?

Tags: sql, oracle

As the title says, is it possible to return nothing from a PL/SQL function?

My function is as follows, and I am getting errors when I leave out the return:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION DeleteAttributes
(code IN varchar2)
CURSOR c_attributes = SELECT ...

BEGIN
    FOR attribute_record IN c_attributes
    LOOP
        ...
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: A function...without a return...is a procedure.  A donut...without a hole...is a danish.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Oracle PL/SQL functions *must* have a return. If you declare your subprogram as a procedure, then it won't give you errors when it is lacking a return (procedures *can't* have a return).

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE DeleteAttributes
(code IN varchar2)
CURSOR c_attributes = SELECT ...

BEGIN
    FOR attribute_record IN c_attributes
    LOOP
        ...
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Procedures CAN have a return statement. You can't return a value, and it's not required, but you can use RETURN in your procedure.

Comment: @DCookie: So what does `RETURN;` do in a procedure? Does it just end execution of the procedure of it right there?

Comment: It leaves the procedure and returns to the caller.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that a function must always return a value. This helps

Answer (score 4):

By definition, a function returns a value, so you must have a RETURN statement. Have a look at the [syntax definition for a function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm) in the Oracle documentation. RETURN is not an option.

I'm not even sure why you would want to do this.